# no action was found on web api 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This controller is working is working fine:

```
[Route("Create")]         
[HttpPost]         
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
}

//But this one is not :` [Route("FindByEmail")]

[HttpGet]
// [ActionName("FindByEmail")]
// [NonAction] 
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FindByEmail(string email)
{
}
```

I'm getting this response:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:35181/api/Account/FindByEmail'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'Account' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

This is a part of my web.config file `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "CategoryApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{category}/{id}",
            defaults: new { category = "all", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
         );`
```

I have tried several distinct routing and read this many posts and Microsoft documentations, but I'm still unable to find a solution.

Comment: Does it help if you adjust the order of your routes, e.g. put the ActionApi route above the CategoryApi route?

The bit which should match "FindByEmail" is {action}, but the route template for CategoryApi is also probably matching the route and thinking "FindByEmail" is the {category}.

Comment: thx for the answer, there was not need for multiple route, i was not calling the api correctly, "path/FindByEmail?email=" + email worked,